# How to do DELETE request in MongoJS?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, http-delete, mongojs

I am just making a simple contactlist app, and this is what I did for deleting a record, It stops the server on pressing the delete button but the next time I start the server, it has deleted the record(i.e shows the correct list)

The other requests `GET` and `POST` work fine.

In `server.js`

```
app.delete('/contactlist/:id',function (req,res) {
var id = req.params.id;

console.log(id);

db.contactlist.remove({'_id' : mongojs.ObjectId(id)},function (err,docs) {
    res.json(doc);
   })
});
```

In `controller.js`

```
$scope.remove = function (id) {
    console.log(id);

    $http.delete('/contactlist/' + id).then(function(response){
        refresh();
    });
};
```

In `index.html`

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove(contact._id)">Delete</button>
```

On pressing the delete function it shows this

```
Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"DELETE","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/contactlist/596bbb440b53b7584765b490","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}
```

Please help! The server stops working, though the next time I start it deletes the record and shows list without the deleted record.

Comment: Status of -1 usually indicate a [CORS problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in `server.js` , it should be `doc` and not `docs`

Rest all fine! Works Well!